# Java method in class cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to call a method named `searchitem` in class `Query` to a jbutton named Search which will search all details in table item in the database and display them in jtextfields. Below is the `searchitem` method in class Query.

```
public ResultSet searchitem() {
    try {
        String sql = "select * from tblitem";
        stmt = conn.connect.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        return rs;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("SQL Exception in Seach Book "+ex.getMessage());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in Retriving Book Information", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        Logger.getLogger(Query.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is the to do code in the jbutton.

```
try {

        String id, nme,cos,pr,available,sid,search;

       search= stf1.getText();

        if(search.length()!=5 || !search.toLowerCase().startsWith("i")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect Item ID \nItem ID should start with 'i' and 5 characters should be used ", "Error", WIDTH);
        }


        else{
            Query query = new Query();
            rs = query. searchitem(search);
            rs.next();

            id = rs.getString(1);
            nme= rs.getString(2);
            cos = rs.getString(3);
            pr = rs.getString(4);
            available = rs.getString(5);
            sid = rs.getString(6);

           boolean availablity = Boolean.valueOf(available);

            etf1.setText(id);
            etf2.setText(nme);
            etf3.setText(cos);
            etf4.setText(pr);
            ecb1.setSelected(availablity);
            etf5.setText(sid);
        }

          } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item not Available. \nEnter an existing Item ID", "Unavailable", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.out.println("SQL Exception in retriving Item details");
        Logger.getLogger(Item.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

But i get an error in line `rs = query. searchitem(search);` saying

method searchitem in class Query cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Obviously `searchitem` does not accept arguments - as the exception so clearly states.

Comment: The error message is very clear. What exactly do you not understand about it? The method `searchitem()` does not take any parameters, but you are trying to call it with one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your method segnature has no argument: `public ResultSet searchitem() {`.

But you call it with one argument `rs = query. searchitem(search);`. that does not fit.

So remove the argument when you call the function, or implement a function that expect one parameter of the correct type